# Creating a roll over pointer animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an effect that when you roll over an image a pointer will point towards it. The same as used in this website about half way down: https://thecleansekitchen.com.au/

[image]

I'm not sure where to begin or if there are any JQuery or plugins out there for this but I cant find any?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are some jQuery plugins out there that do this but that's probably unnecessary. You can accomplish this pretty easily with some basic HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I created a JSFiddle to try to help you get started. https://jsfiddle.net/x823m6ff/

Note that the above is very crude and you'll definitely need to massage it for your needs but hopefully it will help you start down the right path.

I'll lay out the code here as well to explain.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the HTML, I created a container with three blocks (like your screenshot). Each block has a child `arrow` element that is hidden through CSS.

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;

    border-top: 25px solid #FFF;
}
```

The CSS sets up some widths and heights for our blocks and creates the arrow elements. We're positioning these arrow elements relative to each block and putting them at the top middle of each block.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.block').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.arrow').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.arrow').hide();        
    });
});
```

The above JavaScript is very simple and basically just listens for a mouse hover over our block and shows / hides our arrow depending on the state of the user's mouse over the block.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Good starting point. Trying to get my head around everything still. Could I add text to that?

Comment: @HenryBrown You can do anything you can imagine. I'd encourage you to play around with the above example and research some of the other things you want to do online. I think you'll find that you can learn it better if you struggle with it for a bit. Feel free to ask more specific questions if you get stuck! (Some people don't like if you ask very broad, overarching questions on this site, so try to keep it small and specific and show your attempts to solve the problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll play around